# Open and close accordeon with a navigation

Tags: accordion

I´ve got 5 catagories (cat 1, cat 2, cat3.....) and i want that all of the categories are shown, when i click on a navigation item, all the other gets closed and only the selected one is shown, just like an accordeon  and when I deselect the nav item, all categories get schon again.

#### HTML

```
<div id="main-column-4082" class="mod_article block">
<div class="download_nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav_cat1">Cat 1</li>
        <li class="nav_cat2">Cat 2</li>
        <li class="nav_cat3">Cat 3</li>
        <li class="nav_cat4">Cat 4</li>
        <li class="nav_cat5">Cat 5</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="ce_text ce_downloads cat1 block">
    <h3>Cat 1</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="ce_text ce_downloads cat2 block">
    <h3>Cat 2</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="ce_text ce_downloads cat3 block">
    <h3>Cat 3</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="ce_text ce_downloads cat4 block">
    <h3>Cat 4</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
<div class="ce_text ce_downloads cat5 block">
    <h3>Cat 5</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
        <li>Test Item</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Fz33q/5/

Can you help me with that problem?

Comment: do u mean all details of categories must be shows by default when first loaded? and when clicked on Cat1 then show only cat1 else show all?

Comment: Yes, almost like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Fz33q/6/
and how can i give the selected nav item an active class?

Comment: do u mean the title(horizontal categories on top) or the listed that is on left(vertical)?

Comment: I mean the horizontal on top that looks like a navigation.

Comment: __[SOLVED]__ please check the edit i have created DEMO for  your requirement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check here for

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VGb9u/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $topLevelItems = $("inhalte");

    $("#nav_cat1").click(function(){

    $(".cat2").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat3").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat4").slideUp(300);
        $('#nav_cat2').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat3').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat4').css('color','black');
    $('#nav_cat1').css('color','red');
    $(".cat1").delay(400).slideDown(300);

  });
  $("#nav_cat2").click(function(){

    $(".cat1").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat3").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat4").slideUp(300);
    $('#nav_cat1').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat3').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat4').css('color','black');
    $('#nav_cat2').css('color','red');
     $(".cat2").delay(400).slideDown(300);
  });
  $("#nav_cat3").click(function(){

    $(".cat1").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat2").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat4").slideUp(300);
    $('#nav_cat1').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat2').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat4').css('color','black');
    $('#nav_cat3').css('color','red');
    $(".cat3").delay(400).slideDown(300);
  });

  $("#nav_cat4").click(function(){


     $(".cat1").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat2").slideUp(300);
    $(".cat3").slideUp(300);
    $('#nav_cat1').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat2').css('color','black');
        $('#nav_cat3').css('color','black');
    $('#nav_cat4').css('color','red');
      $(".cat4").delay(400).slideDown(300);
  });


});
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, this works awsome, do you know how i can deselect an top menue item to show all items again?

Comment: i think u should have one more button to show all menus "Show all" else an icon. please check the updated fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/VGb9u/4/ and plz mark as answer it it helps you! :)